# Visual Studio Error: Master edit already in progress

Tags: visual-studio

In source view when I am trying to edit something a dialogue box is coming saying "Master edit already in progress" as shown in the below image

[image]

What could be the reason ?
Just closing the form and re-opening it resolves the issue, but I want know, what is happening behind the scene ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bug in Visual Studio 2010/2012. In recent builds, Microsoft has fixed this issue. Although they haven't told about why this issue was coming, but updating my Visual Studio 2012 fixed this.

Reference: 
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/481811/html-editor-gives-master-edit-already-in-progress

Comment: Microsoft has not fixed it yet because I just received this same error in Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 (the latest version).  So maybe you should not say someone has fixed an issue until you know it.

Comment: I just received the same error in Visual Studio 2015 too

Comment: Its not just in VS 2010 and 2012 but in 2013 as well with the latest updates installed. The issue has NOT been fixed. Its surprising the number of times I have seen this and its sister issue "Attempted TextBuffer edit operation while another edit is in progress."  The only thing I can do after getting one of these is to exit and restart the application.  If ever there was a bug in VS that needed to be fixed it is this one, and yet MS still has not fixed it even after years of complaints.

Comment: This just happened to me and I'm using VS 2015 latest. This was never fixed and I had to restart the app to get it to allow anything.

Comment: ...and ditto VS2017Pro :-\

Comment: And VS2017 Enterprise.  It's worse, though, since sometimes the cut code is gone, and undo doesn't bring it back.

Comment: I just got the same error in Visual Studio 2022. See you in 2024, I guess.

Answer (score 6):

I am getting this in VS 2017

For me, usually comes after a variable rename, but I cant reproduce it reliably.

You can close the file and reopen it and that usually fixes it.

Not great, but better by a minute or so than closing and reopening VS.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error as well.  duplicates each line of code twice, temporarily though.  Then if you attempt to edit any line of code after the duplication of the code goes away, I get the error:

> Attempted TextBuffer edit operation while another edit is in progress

Have to restart VS 2015 to resolve the issue.